# Bootstrap sides whitespace

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, whitespace, removing-whitespace

I'm having some trouble fixing the whitespace that is on both sides of my website when the screen resolution is too big (I'm using background images). Using dev tools in browser there's indeed some paddings and margins affecting both my header and footer but simply doing `padding-left: 0` and `padding-right: 0` does not work, not even with `!important`. I think it has to do with Bootstrap's `row` class.

```css
header { 
  height: 708px; 
  background-image: url("Images/hero.png"); 
  background-position: top; 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  text-align: center; 
  color: #22292B; 
  font-family: Windlass; 
  padding-top: 13em; 
}
```

```html
<header class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 hero-bg">
      <h1>
        <b>THE PIRATES</b>
      </h1>
      <h3>El Mar Caribe del Siglo XVII como nunca lo habías experimentado</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 center-block" id="flecha-container">
      <img src="Images/arrow.png" alt="flecha" id="flecha">
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Here's a link to the website: www.davidliu.co/thepirates/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your style is probably being overridden by default, or it might be in the wrong spot, or you target the element wrong. Post the code please

Comment: Sorry for no formatting.                 <header class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 hero-bg">
                <h1><b>THE PIRATES</b></h1>
                <h3>El Mar Caribe del Siglo XVII como nunca lo habías experimentado</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-5 center-block" id="flecha-container">
                <img src="Images/arrow.png" alt="flecha" id="flecha">
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

Comment: Here's the css: header {
    height: 708px;
    background-image: url("Images/hero.png");
    background-position: top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: center;
    color: #22292B;
    font-family: Windlass;
    padding-top: 13em;
}

Comment: In the future, please edit your question instead. It makes the question easier to read and there is support for code formatting. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are looking to do, but if you just want to remove the whitespace between the sides and your header background-image, simply add this:

```css
background-size: cover;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Damn how could I have forgotten about that! It was indeed background-size: cover. Well I guess we all have those moments.

Comment: Absolutely- happens all the time!